# Ruby viewpoint with EWS

Tags: ruby, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get started using `viewpoint` against `EWS` within `Ruby`, and it's not making a lot of sense at the moment.  I am wondering where I can get some good example code, or some `pointers`?  I am using `1.0.0-beta`.

**For example**: I know the name of the `calendar` folder I want to use, so I could search for it, but how to access methods in that folder once I find it?  What are the appropriate `parameters`, etc...

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't read it yet I would recommend the README file in the repository. It has a couple of examples that should put you on the right path. Also, the generated API documentation should give you enough to work with.

http://rubydoc.info/github/WinRb/Viewpoint/frames

At a very basic level you can get all of your calendar events with the following code:

```
calendar = client.get_folder :calendar
events   = calendar.items
```

I hope that gives you a little more to get started with.

**Follow-up:**

Again, I would point you to the [API docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/WinRb/Viewpoint/frames) for concrete methods like #items. There are however dynamically added methods depending on the type that you can fetch with `obj.ews_methods`. In the case of CalendarItem one of those methods is `#name` so you can call obj.name to get the folder name. The dynamic methods are all backed by a formatted Hash based on the returned SOAP packet. You can see it in its raw format by issuing `obj.ews_item`

Cheers,

Dan

Comment: I had read it, and I have been able to pull down folders and even events ... I'm just not sure how to manipulate them beyond that.  For example, extracting a list of participants.